# Querying nested objects in PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb, nosql

I googled some examples and tutorials but couldn't find any clear example for my case.

I get a JSON response from my server like this:

```
var heroes = [
{
    id: 5,
    name: 'Batman',
    realName: 'Bruce Wayne',
    equipments: [
        {
            type: 'boomarang',
            name: 'Batarang',
        },

        {
            type: 'cloak',
            name: 'Bat Cloak',
        },

        {
            type: 'bolas',
            name: 'Bat-Bolas',
        }       
    ]
},
{
    id: 6,
    name: 'Cat Woman',
    realName: 'Selina Kyle',
    equipments: [
        {
            type: 'car',
            name: 'Cat-illac',
        },

        {
            type: 'bolas',
            name: 'Cat-Bolas',
        }      
    ]
}
];
```

I would like to query for example: "get heroes with equipment type of bolas"
and It should return both hero objects in an array.

I know it is not right but what I am trying to do is to form a map function like this:

```
function myMapFunction(doc) {

    if(doc.equipments.length > 0) {
        emit(doc.equipment.type);    
    }

}

db.query(myMapFunction, {
    key: 'bolas',
    include_docs: true
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Is it possible? If not what alternatives do I have?

P.S: I also checked LokiJS and underscoreDB. However PouchDB looks more sophisticated and capable of such query.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map function should be:

```
function myMapFunction(doc) {
  doc.equipments.forEach(function (equipment) {
    emit(equipment.type);
  });
}
```

Then to query, you use `{key: 'bolas'}`:

```
db.query(myMapFunction, {
  key: 'bolas', 
  include_docs: true
}).then(function (result) {
  // got result
});
```

Then your result will look like:

```
{
  "total_rows": 5,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "doc": ...,
      "key": "bolas",
      "id": ...,
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "doc": ...,
      "key": "bolas",
      "id": ...,
      "value": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Also be sure to create an index first! Details are in the [PouchDB map/reduce guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nolan. I will also read your blog on 12 tips for  PouchDB =)

Comment: I also read that "always ask your self, if it is possible to achieve with allDocs()" something like that. In this case, is it possible? Though I am asking to you, not to myself ...

Comment: In this case, it would probably not be possible, since every superhero can have multiple weapons. If they only had one weapon, then yes. :)

Comment: Thanks again Nolan. I also read about the primary keys and how to abuse them. I will keep that technique in mind too.